# In QtWebkit, how to set callback property from js to QObject?

Tags: javascript, qtwebkit

I added an object to the JavaScript context with
`addToJavaScriptWindowObject()`. Works great. Now I wish to specify a
JavaScript callback function to be called from Qt:

```
function cb()
{
    foo = bar;
}
MyObject.cbfun = cb;
```

I know it's easy to call the JavaScript function "cb" with `evaluateJavaScript()`, but that requires a prior knowledge of the callback function name -- this is not what I need

In my Qt object (MyObject) I see the QVariant Q_PROPERTY cbfun is
actually a QVariantMap. How can I call JavaScript function reverenced by
cbfun from my Qt object?